# How to run a function through my plugin page and print the result on that same page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to add a debug page to my website. This page is simply dedicated to  running some of the tasks done by my plugin and outputting some results on the same page.

I currently have a separate page in my Wordpress admin, this page contains a form and button that should be linked to a function that will do various steps and then return a value that must be printed on that page.

Here's the current code for the page and button :

```
function actu_admin_menu_option()
{
    add_menu_page('Scripts', 'Sahar actus plugin', 'manage_options', 'actu-admin-menu', 'actu_scripts_page', '', 200);
}


add_action('admin_menu', 'actu_admin_menu_option');


// HTML page of the plugin 
function actu_scripts_page()
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Sahar actus plugin</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="start_test"> 
            <input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Start test">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}

function start_test()
{
    return ("test started!");
}
add_action( 'admin_post_start_test', 'start_test' );
```

What I would like is for example to run the following function when clicking on the button and then outputting the returned value on the page.

```
    function start_test()
    {
      return("test started!");
    }
```

So when I press the button I want "test started!" to be printed on the page, currently clicking on the button redirects me to `/wp-admin/admin-post.php` which is a blank page.

I have no idea what is the best course of action to do it, should I make an ajax request on my button to run the function and then get the return value from that ajax call ? Or is there a better way to go about this ?

Thanks for helping me, have a great day

EDIT : Updated code, no errors but output is still not printed to page or console.

```
function actu_scripts_page()
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Sahar actu plugin</h2>
         <form action="" method="post">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('do_test', '_test_nonce') ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="start_test">
            <input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Start test">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['start_test'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['start_test'])) {
            if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_test_nonce'], 'do_test')) {
                // error in nonce
            } else {
                start_test();
            }
        }
    } 
    ?>
<?php

}

function start_test()
{
    echo("hhhhh");
    die(); // tried with and without, no difference 

}
    add_action('admin_post_start_test', 'start_test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to acheive this, both are fine, it just depends on the user experience you desire. Use the normal http form submission (what you have already), or use ajax. The normal form submission is the easiest method.

Submit the form using the standard method (what you have there), which will reload the page. **Important Note** it would be better to leave the action attribute blank like `action=""` if you are submitting the page to itself. 
You will also want to add a nonce to the form using `wp_nonce_field()` and check its value in the submission block with `wp_verify_nonce()`.

So your form would like something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('do_test', '_test_nonce') ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="start_test"> 
   <input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Start test">
</form>
```

Add a php block to check if the form has been submitted and do your script in there, printing any output with php.

```
function start_test() {
   // do things. If successful, return true. Otherwise return false
   return true;
}
if( isset($_POST['start_test']) ) {
   if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_test_nonce'], 'do_test' ) {
      // error in nonce
   } else {
      if( start_test() )
         echo '<p>Success!</p>';
      else
         echo '<p>Failure!</p>';  
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the ways to do it!
I've tried your code and it runs but nothing gets printed on the page or in the console, I'll paste back the code in the original post and would greatly appreciate if you could still help me a bit! Thanks for the help, I come from other languages and it's kind of pain to get started doing even the most basic things.

Comment: That's because your function is only _returning_ text, not _echoing_ anything!

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning a lot on how it's working by your examples!
Sadly it's still not printing anything after using your example, maybe this is working fine but doesn't appear because of the way the page gets loaded ? I tried adding die() to every step as Ali_K suggested in his answer but this doesn't work as well. 

Maybe the way I've setup the menu page isn't right ?

Comment: It perhaps _is_ printing to the page, but you just can't see it because it's coming out after the <div class="wrap"> element. Move the closing </div> tag _after the conditional isset block.

Answer (score 0):

There is a redirection happening through /wp-admin/admin-post.php that will return you back to the previous screen.

Your results are being printed on this page, and since it's redirecting, you don't get to see anything.

All you need to do to solve this issue, is add this after your debugging code:

```
die();
```

Or

```
exit();
```

This will stop the PHP from executing anything after your code. Thus, stopping the page from redirecting. Also, any functions that will run after you function, will not run normally, so if you're expecting saving for example, it won't happen after this piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using die in conjunction with the code provided by JakeParis but it's still not outputting anything to the page.